# Prove if $X_n \stackrel{\mathbb P}\to X$ then $\mathbb E|X_n - X|^c \to 0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $c > 0$ and $\mathbb E|X_n|^c$ exists. Prove if $X_n \stackrel{\mathbb P}\to X$ then $\mathbb E|X_n - X|^c \to 0$.

And the opposite seems to be true too.

For $c = 1$ this seems clear, somewhere I even saw the answer to this question, but overall it is not clear.

Comment: Your measure theory text should have an example where $X_n$ converges to $X$ in probability, but $X_n$ does not converge to $X$ in $L^1$ norm.

Comment: $\mathbb E|X_n|^c$ exists for all $n$, some $n$ or the limit exists?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, even for $c=1$.  Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and set $X_n(\omega) := n1_{\omega \le \frac{1}{n}}$.  Then $(X_n) \stackrel{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} 0$ so $X(\omega)=0$ and $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|] = 1$, but $\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|]=1 \not\rightarrow 0$.